# Why does SignTool return a file not found error?

Tags: code-signing, signtool

I am trying to sign an application with my new code signing key, but SignTool keeps giving me a `File not Found: C:\Users\Eaton`

Why? The paths are all correct. When I put the key in the same dir and just put `CodeSigningKey.pfx` without the path, it works fine, but I don't want to do that, I want it to be in that specified path.

Here is my command, the `/f` param being the problem:

```
signtool sign /f C:\Users\Eaton\Desktop\Other Things\CodeSigningKey.pfx /p dsdsds /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode app.exe
```

What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Btw, with the example command, you should be getting `File not Found: C:\Users\Eaton\Desktop\Other` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path to the cert file contains a space and since you have not put it in quotes, the command line arguments parsing treats it as a two separate arguments.

Try this one instead:

```
signtool sign /f "C:\Users\Eaton\Desktop\Other Things\CodeSigningKey.pfx" /p dsdsds /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode app.exe
```

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. How about accepting my answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

While Franci's solution above set me in the right direction I found it didn't quite work in my case.

To resolve, I needed to go to Inno Setup > Tools > Configure tools ...

click the 'Add' button and then respond as follows:

Name of Signtool:
MySignTool

Command of Signtool:

"c:\fullpath\signtool.exe" sign /f "C:\fullpath\CodeSigningKey.pfx" /p mypassword /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode $f

Then in the Inno Setup script itself, under the [Setup] section, I updated the following:
SignTool=MySignTool
SignedUninstaller=true
etc.